# Using toString()'s argument to output letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, tostring

I don't understand what's happening here:

```
var x = 14;
alert(x.toString(36)); //alerts 'e'

alert(x.toString(16)); //also alerts 'e'

x = 20;
alert(x.toString(16)); //alerts '14'
alert(x.toString(36)); //alerts 'k'
```

I think the first parameter determines the numerical system of the number to be converted, but I am not sure. 
Can anybody explain in detail what exactly is going on?

Comment: Yes, I checked that answer. I needed some more information about using the method to convert to letters.

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to get the letter that is represented by the character code '14'?

Comment: @talemyn yes, the whole script is supposed to convert character codes into letters. I was unsure how the parameter could be used to perform such an operation.

Comment: @Rasteril anything higher than base 10 runs out of numerical digits and begins using the alphabet for digits. This is why 36 (10 digits + 26 letters) is the max.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the bases by passing the number parameter.  The second example is easiest to explain . . . 14 in base16 is 'e'.  The base16 'digits' are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a (10), b (11), c (12), d (13), e (14), and f (15).

For any number system of 15 or above, actually, 14 will = 'e'.

In the case of 20, base16 gives you 14, be cause you have 1 sixteen, plus 4 ones (16 + 4 = 20).

To level set, in decimal (base10 . . . the system that we are most used to), 14 technically is 1 ten plus 4 ones.

If you are not familiar with the different numbering systems, it can take a little getting used to.   :)

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is the radix.

```
number.toString( [radix] )
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

> The Number object overrides the toString method of the Object object;
>   it does not inherit Object.toString. For Number objects, the toString
>   method returns a string representation of the object in the specified
>   radix.
>
> The toString method parses its first argument, and attempts to return
>   a string representation in the specified radix (base). For radixes
>   above 10, the letters of the alphabet indicate numerals greater than
>   9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), a through f are used.
>
> If toString is given a radix not between 2 and 36, an exception is
>   thrown.
>
> If the radix is not specified, the preferred radix is assumed to be
>   10.

Answer (score 0):

The optional argument is the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).